# Descobrir hosts da rede

Tags: python, linux, redes

Ao tentar criar um script sobre o assunto fiquei com algumas duvidas sobre o script abaixo! A questão é, como que eu vou fazer o "for i in 100" para que ele dê um ping nos ips, tipo assim 192.168.0.1/192.168.0.2/.../.../192.168.0.100.

**Código:**

```
import os

os.system('clear')
ip = int(input('IP INICIAL (192.168.0.1); '))
print ('Testing...')
for i in 100:
    rs = os.system('ping -c1', ip, +i)
    if rs == 0:
        print ('O', ip, 'ta on')
```

**Erro:**

```
> IP INICIAL (192.168.0.1); 192.168.2.0

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/root/redes/redes.py", line 4, in <module>
    ip = int(input('IP INICIAL (192.168.0.1); '))
  File "<string>", line 1
    192.168.2.0
            ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Não pode ler o ip como inteiro pois ele tem varios `.` pelo meio, que é na verdade o erro que aparece na imagem que colocou.

O mais facil é mesmo tratar o ip como uma lista de inteiros. E para isso pode utilizar a função `split` da `string` que separa em vários valores mediante um separador. No seu caso interessa utilizar o `.` como separador.

```
ip = input('IP INICIAL (192.168.0.1); ').split('.')
```

Veja como é interpretado

```
>>> ip = input('IP INICIAL (192.168.0.1); ').split('.')
IP INICIAL (192.168.0.1); 192.168.1.1
>>> ip
['192', '168', '1', '1']
```

Cada parte do ip não é de facto um numero e sim uma `string`, no entanto, não tem relevância para o que está a fazer que é substituir o ultimo bloco dinamicamente. Agora já estamos no ponto de construir o for que queria:

```
import os

os.system('clear')
ip = input('IP INICIAL (192.168.0.1); ').split('.')
print ('Testing...')
for i in range(1,101): # faltou range aqui
    ip[3] = str(i) # mudar a ultima parte do ip para o numero como string
    ip_formatado = '.'.join(ip) # criar o texto que representa o ip
    rs = os.system('ping -c 1 {}'.format(ip_formatado)) # executar o comando com o ip certo
    if rs == 0:
        print ('O {} ta on'.format(ip_formatado))
```

Note que tinha o comando com `-c1` junto quando era suposto ser separado por espaço.

Construí o texto do ip de volta utilizando a função `join` com `ip_formatado = '.'.join(ip)`, o que simplifica bastante. Veja um exemplo desta parte apenas a funcionar:

```
>>> ip = ['192', '168', '1', '1']
>>> ip
['192', '168', '1', '1']
>>> '.'.join(ip)
'192.168.1.1'
```

Comment: MT OBRIGADO MANO, NAMORAL TE AMO <3

Answer (score -3):

```
def scan_ip_range(range_de_ips):
    for IP_Range in range(1, 255):
        requests = os.system("ping -c 2 {}.{}".format(IP, IP_Range))

scan_ip_range('IP_Range')
```

Essa forma que eu fiz é muito mais simples, o problema é que aparece tanto o resultado dos hosts ativos como dos que não estão.

Comment: Bem vindo ao Stack Overflow. Antes de usar site veja os links na [help] e [answer]. O Stack Overflow não é um fórum, chat ou grupo de discussão. Somos um site de perguntas e respostas, e a maneira com publicou a sua solução está com a leitura incompreensível pois o sistema não mantem a ordem de criação das publicações com mesma pontuação. Por favor reúna esse texto espalhado em uma única publicação Aproveite e faça o nosso [tour].